# Firebase cloud messing : How to differentiate among different topics

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is topic subscription function in firebase cloud messaging.

But, how do I differentiate which messages received through notification belong to which topic?

When I subscribe to a topic for example.

```
 Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "news")
```

And when I send the message, I receive the message from the back end in this format in the app .

```
    the full messag is this = [AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("google.c.a.ts"): 1500271703, AnyHashable("google.c.a.udt"): 0, AnyHashable("gcm.n.e"): 1, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "google is hello world";
}, AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_id"): 967226232057261708, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1500271704062691%515abe1d515abe1d]
```

As we can see that, the message we receive contains no "topic" field. So how do we know whether this message is sent under "news" topic or another topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud messaging work as Triggers in database, in our Programming we defined one receiver for receive any trigger call and another is handler for handle that function during receive a Trigger call.Every Trigger defined by a unique identifier for handle all these procedure.

Firebase cloud message help to implement instant chat functionality in a application because these trigger directly connect with firebase database. Whenever we do any thing in database like Addition,Deletion,Insertion and updating then Trigger automatic reflect in a project.

Thanks